# Backbone View events not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created a simple backbone page, it fetches some settings (JSON) from server and inserts them in a table (each row is a `settingModel` instance).

Now I wanted to use events in order to change my models' attributes, when user changes them and sync settings with server.

I used the following code for the model's view:

```
app.settingView = Backbone.View.extend ({  // View for Model

  tagName: 'tr',

  template: _.template( $('#setting-template').html() ),

  events: {
    'focus input':'showAlert'
  },

  render: function () {
    var modelData = this.model.toJSON();
    var settingTemplate = this.template(modelData);
    this.$el.html(settingTemplate);
    return this;
  },

  showAlert: function(){
    alert("You Are Editing");
  }
});
```

but it does not fire the event, the same event works when I used inline `onfocus="alert()"` in my `input` tag.

I created a fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/7348/)**

Comment: @ivarni Yes! this fixes the events problem, but there are some styling problems that I'll fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because here:

```
$('.container').html($(settingsView.render().el).html());
```

you are using the HTML contents of the View's element. You should append the View's *element* itself.

```
$('.container').append(settingsView.render().el);
```

This is because Backbone uses event delegation syntax for binding the view event handlers. Since you are appending the html representation of View's contents the appended elements are not descendants of the View's element and as a result the event doesn't propagate to the View's element.

Comment: yes... but that's because the `tbody` can not have any child  tag

Comment: @Webinan What exactly do you mean by "that's because the tbody can not have any child tag"? That's not true. `tbody` can have `tr` children.

Comment: I mean that if I have e.g. `tagName: 'div'` for the collection then I can not put the div in the `tbody` , and I have to put it's contents (`.html()`) inside `tbody`

Comment: @Webinan In that case you should use a `tr` element, not a `div` element. Creating a View constructor for just using it's _html representation_ doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Note that you can also append/move the children of the wrapper view instead of appending the html representation. `yourCollectionView.$el.children().appendTo('.container')`

Comment: the `tr` element is for `model`s, the problem is the collections's container, you say I should put 3 `tr`s in another `tr` and put all of them in `tbody`!?

Comment: @Webinan No, that generates invalid markup, You actually don't have to have a collection view if you don't want to append it.

Comment: I want to append it, but I just want to get rid of it's root element.